# Android: Send image to server

Tags: android, image

EDIT So  I Have found the error. when ever the phone changes orientation it looses the picture thats why its null, How can I resolve this ? I want it to always be Potrait, but even thought i have set it from the manifest file to have this orientation locked when I use the camera it looses it...

Hello I have this code that takes a picture and show it in my imageview this works great what I want now is to send this picture via longblob to my database

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAM_REQUEST) {
        Bitmap thumpnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ingTakenPhoto.setImageBitmap(thumpnail);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumpnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
        encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

    }
}
```

but when ever I try to put this in my encoded I get an error that my volley for encoded is null 
here is the line that is in fault

```
      protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {



                    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    parameters.put("firstname", firstname.toString());
                    parameters.put("lat", lat.toString());
                    parameters.put("lon", lon.toString());
                    parameters.put("email", textEmail.toString());
                    parameters.put("description", textViewDescription.getText().toString());
                    parameters.put("image", encoded);

                    return parameters;


                }
            };
```

the error

> 05-16 17:19:42.150 14821-14821/com.example.chara.reaction I/System.out: com.android.volley.VolleyError: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
>   05-16 17:20:15.870 14821-14821/com.example.chara.reaction V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{3d021db1 token=android.os.BinderProxy@3a8c9999 {com.example.chara.reaction/com.example.chara.reaction.HomeActivity}} show : true

Comment: provide error message and sending method.

Comment: Please post codes sorrounding ` parameters.put("image", encoded.toString());` It might be some scope issue.

Comment: 05-16 17:19:42.150 14821-14821/com.example.chara.reaction I/System.out: com.android.volley.VolleyError: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
05-16 17:20:15.870 14821-14821/com.example.chara.reaction V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{3d021db1 token=android.os.BinderProxy@3a8c9999 {com.example.chara.reaction/com.example.chara.reaction.HomeActivity}} show : true
05-16 17:23:35.570 14821-14828/com.example.chara.reaction W/art:  
I dont know how  how i send, Hashmapping ? PUT method

Comment: Add this to the question. and try make break point before sending data and what you can see in request params.

Comment: Edited the original post witth those codes asked

Comment: xAqueRx I have found the error. it changes orientation when ever  I use the camera to take the picture  even though I have this in the manifests android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" ,